# Cumulative sum over days in python

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe:

```
        date      money
0     2018-01-01     20
1     2018-01-05     30
2     2018-02-15     7
3     2019-03-17     150
4     2018-01-05     15
...
2530  2019-03-17     350
```

And I need:

```
[(2018-01-01,20),(2018-01-05,65),(2018-02-15,72),...,(2019-03-17,572)]
```

So i need to do a cumulative sum of money over all days:
So far I have tried many things and the closest Ithink I've got is:

```
graph_df.date = pd.to_datetime(graph_df.date)
temporary = graph_df.groupby('date').money.sum()
temporary = temporary.groupby(temporary.index.to_period('date')).cumsum().reset_index()
```

But this gives me ValueError: Invalid frequency: date

Could anyone help please?

Thanks

Comment: Please add expected output so you can get better answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you need the second groupby. You can simply add a column with the cumulative sum.

This does the trick for me:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['01-01-2019','04-06-2019', '07-06-2019'], 'money': [12,15,19]})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']) # this is not strictly needed

tmp = df.groupby('date')['money'].sum().reset_index()
tmp['money_sum'] = tmp['money'].cumsum()
```

Converting the date column to an actual date is not needed for this to work.

Comment: This one does exactly what I want. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Dominik Novotný then you should accept his answer (and upvote if you like).

Answer (score 1):

```
list(map(tuple, df.groupby('date', as_index=False)['money'].sum().values))
```

---

**Edit**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2018-01-01', '2018-01-05', '2018-02-15', '2019-03-17', '2018-01-05'],
                   'money': [20, 30, 7, 150, 15]})

#df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
#df = df.sort_values(by='date')

temporary = df.groupby('date', as_index=False)['money'].sum()
temporary['money_cum'] = temporary['money'].cumsum()
```

Result:

```
>>> list(map(tuple, temporary[['date', 'money_cum']].values))
[('2018-01-01', 20),
 ('2018-01-05', 65),
 ('2018-02-15', 72),
 ('2019-03-17', 222)]
```

Comment: So basically I got the same answer as BramV with the exception of the last convertion to the list of tuples...

Answer (score 0):

you can try using `df.groupby('date').sum()`:

example data frame:

```
df
         date  money
0  01/01/2018     20
1  05/01/2018     30
2  15/02/2018      7
3  17/03/2019    150
4  05/01/2018     15
5  17/03/2019    550
6  15/02/2018     13



df['cumsum'] = df.money.cumsum()
list(zip(df.groupby('date').tail(1)['date'], df.groupby('date').tail(1)['cumsum']))

[('01/01/2018', 20),
 ('05/01/2018', 222),
 ('17/03/2019', 772),
 ('15/02/2018', 785)]
```

Comment: Thank you, but I need every date only once.
The thing is that I have dates and expected earned interest. And I am plotting a graph of projected interest for that.

Comment: so you just need groupby and sum()

Comment: @DominikNovotný , is that waht you wanted? i update the answer

Comment: Unfortunatelly this is not what I need either. I need for the money column to keep adding up, so the last row with the highest date has the biggest value in money column.